# JQuery UI Sortable item is not detecting a fixed target area when a hidden target area is underneath

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am attempting to create a fixed-position sortable menu where target areas on the right can do a horizontal scroll behind the fixed menu. The problem I'm facing is that when I attempt to drag an item from the fixed menu to a target or vice-versa, it works perfectly fine until I have scrolled and a target area is behind the fixed menu. When this happens, dragging an item to the fixed menu does not work as the item is dropped onto the target area sitting behind the fixed menu.

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/geraldclark/ojkgbLv9/45/

```
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Fixed Menu</th>
        <th>Sortable 1</th>
        <th>Sortable 2</th>
        <th>Sortable 3</th>
        <th>Sortable 4</th>
        <th>Sortable 5</th>
        <th>Sortable 6</th>
        <th>Sortable 7</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <ul class="sortable">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="sortable">
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
            <li>Item 9</li>
            <li>Item 10</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="sortable">
            <li>Item 11</li>
            <li>Item 12</li>
            <li>Item 13</li>
            <li>Item 14</li>
            <li>Item 15</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="sortable">
            <li>Item 16</li>
            <li>Item 17</li>
            <li>Item 18</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 20</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="sortable">
            <li>Item 21</li>
            <li>Item 22</li>
            <li>Item 23</li>
            <li>Item 24</li>
            <li>Item 25</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="sortable">
            <li>Item 26</li>
            <li>Item 27</li>
            <li>Item 28</li>
            <li>Item 29</li>
            <li>Item 30</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="sortable">
            <li>Item 31</li>
            <li>Item 32</li>
            <li>Item 33</li>
            <li>Item 34</li>
            <li>Item 35</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="sortable">
            <li>Item 36</li>
            <li>Item 37</li>
            <li>Item 38</li>
            <li>Item 39</li>
            <li>Item 40</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

```
table {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 200px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
}

thead th {
  background-color: grey;
  min-width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

thead th:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  height: 239px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

tbody td {
  min-width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: white;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody').scroll(function(e) {
    $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft());
    $('thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft());
    $('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft());
  });

  $('.sortable').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    scroll: false,
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: 'body',
  });
});
```

(Note: you may need to expand the view for the table to scroll correctly)

- I can drag from "Fixed Menu" to "Sortable 1"
- I can drag from "Sortable 1" to "Fixed Menu"
- When I scroll to "Sortable 6" and attempt to drag "Item 31" to the "Fixed Menu", it drops to one of the other sortable items right behind it.

I've tried porting this to fixed divs as well with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the sortable interface picking the back list and not the front list to drop to.

Here's a solution that should work. Whenever scrolling, wait to see if the person has stopped scrolling. Then calculate whether a column is covered up by the fixed column, if it is then change it to not be sortable otherwise make it sortable.

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kd8zpo96/1/

The main functions I added to the previous fiddle is this:

```
var isColliding = function( $element1, $element2 ) {
    var allowableOverlap = 5;

    var element1RightDistance = $element1.offset().left 
    + $element1.outerWidth( true );

    //Only care if the Right border of the fixed column is overtop the scrollable column
    return (element1RightDistance > $element2.offset().left + allowableOverlap );
};

$('tbody').scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    //Don't call the function unless stopped for a little bit.
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
      $('.scrollableColumn').each(function(index, element){
        var $element = $(element);
        var colliding = isColliding($('.fixedColumn'), $element);
        $element.find('.sortable').sortable( "option", "disabled", colliding );
      })
    }, 250));
});
```